# como crear un archivo txt desde un formulario php

Tags: php, debian

buenas tengo una duda soy nuevo en php y necesito crear un formulario php y que los datos los almacene en un documento de texto (.txt)
este es el codigo que tengo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Configuracion Red</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" ACTION="registro.php" >
            <table class="formulario">
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        Numero ip :
                    </td>
                    <td class="entrada">
                        <input type "text" id="txtnumeroip" name="txtnumeroip" value="" maxlength = "15"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        Nombre Red Wifi :
                    </td>
                    <td class="entrada">
                        <input type="text" id="txtnombrewifi" name="txtnombrewifi" value="" maxlength="30"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        Clave :
                    </td>
                    <td class="entrada">    
                        <input type="text" id="txtClave" name="txtClave" value="" maxlength="20"  />
                    </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="botonera">
                        <input class="boton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
<?php
    $archivo = "datos.txt";
    $gestor = @fopen("/tmp/datos.txt", "w+");

    fclose($gestor);
?>  
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

recibo los datos aqui

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php

    $numeroIp="";
    if (!empty($_POST["txtnumeroip"]))
    {
        $numeroIp = $_POST["txtnumeroip"];
    }

    $nombrewifi="";
    if (!empty($_POST["txtnombrewifi"]))
    {
        $nombrewifi = $_POST["txtnombrewifi"];
    }

    $clave="";
    if(!empty($_POST["txtClave"]))
    {
        $clave = $_POST["txtClave"];
    }

    $contenido="
numero ip : $numeroip
nombre red wifi : $nombrewifi
clave : $clave
";

    $archivo = fopen("tmp/datos.txt","w+");
    fwrite($archivo,$contenido);
?>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>recibido</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

sin embargo no me crea el archivo en la carpeta tmp

si alguien me puede orientar en que estoy haciendo mal o cual es el error se agradeceria

Comment: coloca en un try/catch la linea fwrite debe tener un error ; ese error colocalo en tu pregunta y con gusto te ayudaremos, cuando se trabaja con archivos usa try catch hay muchas variables por la que pueden fallar

Comment: Esa carpeta tmp donde esta almacenada con respecto al archivo php registro?

Comment: es la carpeta temporal de debían, pero estaba en un error ahí en la dirección. según eh estado mirando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes almacenar los datos de esta manera

```
if (file_exists("tmp/datos.txt")){
$archivo = fopen("tmp/datos.txt", "a");
fwrite($archivo, PHP_EOL ."$contenido");
fclose($archivo);
}
else{
$archivo = fopen("tmp/datos.txt", "w");
fwrite($archivo, PHP_EOL ."$contenido");
fclose($archivo);
   }
```

> PHP_EOL

crea un salto de linea

Comment: disculpa, pero que permisos da la a? habia visto los permisos w,w+,r,r+ pero no la ah
de ante mano gracias :)

Comment: Hola "a". La escritura comenzará al final del archivo sin eliminar el contenido previo existente.  >w: Abre el archivo sólo para escritura. La escritura comienza al inicio del archivo, y elimina el contenido previo del archivo. Si el archivo no existe, intenta crearlo

Comment: “r” es el modo de apertura que abre el archivo sólo para lectura. La lectura comienza al inicio del archivo. Saludes